# How can I test an already established MQ connection in Websphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, message-queue, ibm-mq

I am new to the whole WebSphere world, so I dont know how else to ask this.

Basically, my app already has a QCF, as well as an inbound and outbound queue set up.  I was told a while ago that this environment never had its MQ settings tested properly so its unverified if they work correctly.

Currently I am experiencing problems with my service that uses MQ in this environment and I want to somehow test these connections explicitly.  Is there a way to do this like there is for testing the database connection in WebSphere, with a simply click of a button or something?

As I said, I am new to the WebSphere world so I can probably taking some things for granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are setting up connection factory, you have a test connection button, which tests connection to the queue manager. Unfortunately this button is available only during creation of connection factory. There is no similar 'Test connection' functionality like in Data sources.

I usually use my custom very simple application, which takes qcf and queue from jndi, connects, sends and receives test message.

To just verify that the network is set up correctly, you could use `telnet qmHost qmPort` from application server machine.

If you are getting some exceptions, provide a stacktrace, it might tell something more about your problem